# Managed objects registering for notifications

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsnotifications

Is it bad form for managed objects to add themselves as observers of notifications?  I have a managed object that has several transient properties and gets its data from a different store as described in the CoreData docs.  If the store changes, the managed objects need to listen for this notification and act accordingly.  I was worried that there might be some performance implications to having something like a managed object registering for notifications since there could be quite a lot of them and CoreData manages their lifecycles.

Comment: I don't know what kind of application you are designing, but I am thinking about the fact that NSManagedObjects not loaded yet, probably need to be notified too. If this is the case, I would rather think about an util class listening to notification, which in turn go and modify the store, or lookup for live objects and merge changes.

Comment: Once the managed object becomes loaded it would start with the most up to date data

Answer (score 0):

JPC,

Based on my experience there could be few potential performance problems if you set a `NSManagedObject` as a observer. It could become a bottleneck, but it depends on the number of objects you have and on the type of notification you register for. Could say something more on it?

Said this, I suggest you to read [parent-watching-its-child](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/10/14/parent-watching-its-child/) by **Marcus Zarra**. This article could guide you in the right track.

Hope that helps.